# Scala Spark Mongo - filter with "in" clause

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have a mongoDB collection which is potentially quite big.

I'm using the following connector in order to read data from this collection using spark:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I would like to filter the collection by a closed list (which could also be quite long) of ids, which is fetched from another data source.

I understand from the documentation that some filtering can be pushed down to happen on mongo side.

e.g.

```
rdd.filter(doc => doc.getInteger("test") > 5)
```

I'm to figure if there's a way to perform something similar to:

```
val ids = spark.sql("select ids from some_non_mongo_table")
val mongoDocs = MongoSpark.load(spark.sparkContext, mongoConf)
                          .filter(doc => doc.id in ids)
```

If it is not possible, is there any other reasonable solution except fetching the entire collection from mongo and joining the results with the ids dataframe ?

Comment: performing broadcast inner join against your ID dataframe is neat solution than going for filter(...) approach.

Comment: but in this case i am fetching the entire collection from mongo no ?

Comment: Spark Dataset would load only the required data from source and this is called Predicate pushdown.From my understanding, MangoDB supports Predicate pushdown as described in the below link.

https://www.raphael-brugier.com/blog/introduction-mongodb-spark-connector/#:~:text=Predicates%20pushdown%3A,a%20MongoDB%20aggregation%20pipeline%20match%20.

Predicate filter will happen whether you perform filter or you perform join. 
 Broadcast join would be a better approach if your IDs are expected to grown from few number to ten of thousands.

Comment: I'm checking this approach but as i understand from the blog post, only where clause and select clause are pushed down to mongo.

"Predicates pushdown is an optimization from the Spark SQL’s Catalyst optimizer to push the where filters and the select projections down to the datasource"

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `.filter(doc => ids.contain(doc.id))`?

```
val ids = spark.sql("select ids from some_non_mongo_table").collect.map(r => r(0))

val mongoDocs = MongoSpark.load(spark.sparkContext, mongoConf)
                          .filter(doc => ids.contains(doc.id))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion
I was investigating this approach but had some troubles converting the results to DataFrame.
the result is of type RDD[Document] and although the IDE (intelij) completes the toDF() method it does not compile.

Comment: @OdedRosenberg could you please show any errors when you compile?

Comment: Error:(41, 8) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.bson.Document]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
      .toDF()

Comment: @OdedRosenberg could you try importing `import spark.implicits._`  and try `toDF` again..?

Comment: It is imported within the code scope, I think this works for case classes only

Comment: @OdedRosenberg see this question here - it may be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851476/rdd-of-bsonobject-to-a-dataframe

Comment: thanks for the lead, it is a good step toward working with results as DF.
seems like the filter is not pushed down though when using the list.contains approach.
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#33]
+- Scan[obj#32]

Answer (score 0):

At the end I went with sending the filtering values as pipeline.
Looked like the preferable way as couldn't get the filters to be pushed down in other ways, and fetching the entire collection is too heavy.

```
    // ids is a comma delimited string 
    val pipeline = "{$match: {id : {$in:[" + ids + "]}}}"
    val mongoConf = mongoReadConfig


    val existingSnapshots = MongoSpark
      .load(spark.sparkContext, mongoConf)
      .withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse(pipeline)))
      .toDF()
```